# Perl equivalent of PHP's preg_callback

Tags: php, regex, perl

Do we have a preg_callback equivalent in Perl ?

Lets say I want to match something and replace it with the return value of the function that is called with the matched thing.

Comment: When asking for an equivalent function from another language, it is a good idea to explain what it does and/or link to docs for the function.

Answer (score 22):

Use `s///e` - evaluation modifier and you can put arbitrary perl codes in second part.

```
$x = "this is a test";
$x =~ s/(test)/reverse($1)/eg;
print $x;

//this is a tset
```

ref: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Search-and-replace

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, can you give a short example. Say I want to replace the matched thing with its reverse.

Comment: `my $string = "abc"; (my $reverseString = $string) =~ s/(bc)/reverse $1/e;` will cause `$reverseString` to become `"acb"` . @Joseph : I suggest you edit your question to ask for the reverse example, so I can post this as a separate answer.

Comment: you can also use curly braces as the substitution delimiter which makes the second block a bit more "code like" `s{pattern to match} {reverse($1)}e`